# How to send post request from angular app to spring?

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, post

I am trying to send port request with username and password:

```
signUp(username, password): Observable<String> {
return this.http.post<String>("http://localhost:8080/signUp", {
  params: { username: username, password: password }
});
}
```

To a spring service that has this method:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping(value="/signUp", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> signUp(@RequestParam ("username") String username, @RequestParam("password")  String password) throws IOException {
 //not important
 return new ResponseEntity<String>("Added successfully.", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

When I send it, in angular I get http 400 error. In spring service I see this message:

> 2020-03-13 19:32:38.486  WARN 13200 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'username' is not present]

I know that there are values sent from Angular application in that http request (I checked with hardcoded). Can someone help me solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried passing username and password outside of a 'params' object?

Comment: Seems like you are sending a request body rather than a request param but your backend expects the latter.

Comment: your request payload is `{"params":{"username":"test","password":"test"}}` and this is not what the backend expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there is a confusion between `@RequestBody` and `@RequestParam` - they're two entirely different things.

> @RequestBody Indicates that the API is expecting a request payload

and

> @RequestParam expects one or more params to be passed in to the API
>   url when it is invoked.

Now, the backend expects a *request* parameter to be passed in when it is invoked. For eg: `/signUp/username=abc`, so from the UI you need to pass in this key-value pair i.e

```
http.post<String>(`http://localhost:8080/signUp?username=${username}&password=${password}`)
```

The 400 bad request originates as you are passing in a *request body* rather than a *request parameter*. An alternate solution is to change the backend to accept a request payload - you would then need to use `@RequestBody`.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be this request:

```
signUp(username, password): Observable<String> {
    return this.http.post<String>("http://localhost:8080/signUp", {
          username: username, password: password
    });
}
```

...with a class for the request body in your backend:

```
public class SignUp {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    // constructor, getters and setters or lombok @Data
}
```

...and then in your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/signUp", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> signUp(@RequestBody SignUp signUp) {
    // signUp.getUsername()...
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Added successfully.", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```